# SQL summary by ID with period to period comparison

Tags: sql

I am a beginner in SQL, hope someone can help me on this:

I have a Items Category Table:

```
ItemID | ItemName | ItemCategory | Active/Inactive
100      Carrot      Veg           Yes
101      Apple       Fruit         Yes
102      Beef        Meat          No
103      Pineapple   Fruit         Yes
```

And I have a sales table:

```
Date       | ItemID | Sales
01/01/2010   100      50
05/01/2010   101      200
06/01/2010   101      250
06/01/2010   102      300
07/01/2010   103      50
08/01/2010   100      100
10/01/2010   102      250
```

How Can I achieve a sales summary  table by Item By Period as below (with only active item)

```
ItemID | ItemName | ItemCategory | (01/01/2010 – 07/01/2010) | (08/01/2010 – 14/01/1020)
100      Carrot     Veg             50                         100
101      Apple      Fruit          450                           0
103      Pineapple  Fruit            0                           0
```

Comment: What is the basis for creating the periods? 1 Week always?

Answer (score 0):

A very dirty solution

```
SELECT s.ItemId, 
       (SELECT ItemName FROM Items WHERE ItemId = s.ItemId) ItemName, 
        ISNULL((SELECT Sum(Sales)FROM sales
            WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2010/01/01' AND '2010/01/07'
            AND itemid = s.itemid
            GROUP BY ItemId),0)   as firstdaterange,
        ISNULL((SELECT Sum(Sales)FROM sales
            WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2010/01/08' AND '2010/01/14'
            AND itemid = s.itemid
            GROUP BY ItemId), 0)   seconddaterange
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Items i ON s.ItemId = i.ItemId
WHERE i.IsActive = 'Yes'
GROUP BY s.ItemId
```

Again a dirty solution, also the dates are hardcoded. You can probably turn this into a stored procedure taking in the dates as parameters.

I'm not too clued up on PIVOT command but maybe that will be worth a google.

Comment: It return an error , "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'ISNULL (( SELECT Sum(Sales) FROM Sales WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2010/01/01'  AND '2010/01/07' AND itemid = s.itemid GROUP BY ItemID), 0'.

Comment: What db are you using. I just tried it in mssql and it works fine. Try removing the ISNULL(). I put it in there so it would show 0 instead of nulls for a 0 value.

Comment: Sorry mate, I forgot to mention I am using Microsoft Access, I tried to removed the ISNULL, but the warning I've got is "Data type mismatch in criteria expression", any ideas what caused the error?

Comment: It is no doubt the date formats. Have never spent a lot of time with access so not sure how to specify a between criteria. I will check in a bit.

Comment: Ok it looks like you'll need to try the dates as - between #01/01/2010# and #01/07/2010# - i'm guessing a bit at the date format - assuming mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot the data using the SQL PIVOT operator. Unfortunately, that operator has limited scope due to the requirement to pre-specify the output columns.

You normally achieve this by grouping on a calculated column (in this case, one that computes the week number or first day of the week in which each row falls). You can then either generate SQL on-the-fly with columns derived using `SELECT DISTINCT week FROM result`, or just drop the result into Excel and use its pivot table facility.